# Why is integer 0 equal to a string in PHP?

Tags: php, types, casting, type-conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comparis)

Why this

```
var_dump(0 == "string");
```

outputs this

```
bool(true)
```

Isn't the context of `==` operator supposed to convert `0` into `FALSE` and `"string"` into `TRUE` according to [this set of rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)?

Comment: try `===` and it will give you false i think.

Comment: But even as a comparison, that should be false, no?

Comment: To explain that behavior: You're comparing an integer and a string. PHP converts the string to an int, which is 0 (as it doesn't contain any number representation). 0 == 0 is obviously true.

Comment: First rule of PHP. Learn not to be surprised by anything.

Comment: This is the set of rules you need to refer to: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @Joe - second rule of PHP - If PHP exhibits Documented behaviour then it shouldn't be a surprise

Comment: @MarkBaker that arguably knocks mine off top spot. But I do find the type juggling thing a bit odd. I'd rather have a type cast exception than undocumented behaviour. No need for a religious war, I just found this question amusing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var_dump(0 == "string");
```

is doing a numeric (integer) comparison

0 is an integer, so "string" is converted to an integer to do the comparison, and equates to an integer value of 0, so 0 == 0 is true

Se the [comparison with various types table](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in the PHP documentation for details

Comment: It's still strange that in PHP a non-empty string is equivalent to integer `0`, which goes in conceptual conflict with C, by which PHP is claimed to be influenced. In C, a non-null __something__ casts to `true` or the equivalent integer `1`.

Comment: @Desmond If you cast `"string"` to a number and the string does not contain any numeric value, `0` is the only logical choice. If you cast `"string"` to a `bool`, it'll cast to `true` unless it's empty (for PHP's definition of "empty"). Casting `"string"` to a number and getting `1` is just as illogical and anything else, you just need to learn the rules.

Comment: Hi could you please explain to me why **filter_var(0, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)** return false?.

Comment: I'm crying.....

Answer (score 2):

The [table shown here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) is more fit for your case.

It shows `TRUE` for comparing `0` with `"php"`.

Within the comparison you do not convert both operands to a boolean, but one operand will be converted to match the type of the other operand. In your case the string gets converted to an integer, which results in another `0`. This gives you `0 == 0`, which yields true.

Answer (score 1):

They are not of the same type, use === if you want to check if they are also of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP: ==](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

> If you compare **a number with a string** or the comparison involves
>   numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the
>   comparison performed numerically.

`"string"` is not number format, so it will be convert to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

during the comparison, the string is converted to an integer:

```
var_dump(0);
var_dump((int)"string");
var_dump(0 == "string");
```

last line will be automatically converted to:

```
var_dump(0 == (int)"string");
```

so this return will return:

```
int(0)
int(0)
bool(true)
bool(true)
```

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for the comparison table on this site first: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php. Casting to `bool` doesn't apply here.

```
Operand 1           Operand 2
...
string, resource    string, resource    Translate strings and resources to numbers,
or number           or number           usual math
```

`"string"` cast to a *number* equals `0`.