# Function Output Issues

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I have a function that can either be called by echo or load, in turn also 0 or 1 for echo or load. But, since adding the number variable to the function options, it no longer always works.

Can you please help me?

Here is my function:

```
// GET MAIN INFORMATION
function get_info ($KEY, $OUTPUT = 0) {

$KEY = "_" . strtoupper($KEY);
if ($OUTPUT == "echo" || $OUTPUT == 0):
    echo "echo " . constant($KEY);
elseif ($OUTPUT == "load" || $OUTPUT == 1):
    return "load " . constant($KEY);
endif;

}
```

now when I try to call the function like this:

```
echo 1;
get_info('scripts_url', 'echo');

echo "<br>" . 2;
get_info('scripts_url', 0);

echo "<br>" . 3;
echo get_info('scripts_url', 'load');

echo "<br>" . 4;
echo get_info('scripts_url', 1);
```

This is my output:

```
1echo scripts/ (This is correct!)
2echo scripts/ (This is correct!)
3echo scripts/ (This is not correct!)
4load scripts/ (This is correct!)
```

So there is an issue when I try to use the numbers. Can you see the error and help me correct it?

Thanks

Comment: use `===` instead of `==`.  The non-numeric string `'load'` compares truthfully to integer `0` owing to PHP's type juggling rules, so the first condition will match any string that isn't numeric.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is integer 0 equal to a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970544/why-is-integer-0-equal-to-a-string-in-php)

Comment: If you add that as an answer, i will accept it. Thank you! It works like a charm!

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, your answer is a duplicate, the question is not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: The linked duplicate is a signpost to better & more complete answers on this same issue. I've posted below if you would like to close your question with an accept.

Comment: Why don't you just return the value, then use `echo get_info()`?

Comment: @nic it is just the way I want to do it. The majority of times I use this function, I will be doing so for echo, however, there will be a few times i need it for the variable like in a function, and this way I can do so without having to write echo hundreds of times, and instead only need add `, 0` a few times.

Comment: Well, suit yourself, as long as you don't work with me on the same project...

Comment: Have you every worked with WordPress @nic, because that is how most of their code is ie `the_title();` or you can attach it to a string. It is the a time savor if you are using several instances of the function through out your script with the same outputs needed.

Comment: WordPress isn't really a good coding example (understatement). Which is why I don't use it.

Comment: @nic well give a chance to save a hundred characters in thousands of lines of code, I would choose to save some characters. So I guess I will never be working for you!

Comment: I understand that, and I would have thought the same way a couple of years ago. However, once I started using concepts like Object-oriented Programming, and the Model-View-Controller (MVC) pattern, I stopped using `echo` within functions (and methods) wherever I could. Believe me, even though I had to type some more characters, it made life a lot easier. In the end, good standards save you more time than trying to keep your code as short as possible.

Comment: typing `$get_info->data();` is still way less code than typing `echo $get_info->data();` Maybe one day I will change, but not this day. But I am thinking about getting into more object oriented programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Owing to PHP's [rules for boolean comparisons](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), the non-numeric string `"load"` compares truthfully to the integer `0`.  So your first condition will match any string that can't be converted directly to a non-zero integer.  Instead of loosely comparing via `==`, use a strict comparison via `===`.

```
function get_info($key, $output = 0)
{
    $key = "_" . strtoupper($key);

    // Strict comparisons should be used to avoid strings matching int 0
    if ($output === "echo" || $output === 0) {
        echo "echo " . constant($key); 
    } elseif ($output === "load" || $output === 1) {
        return "load " . constant($key);
    }
}
```

An aside, not relevant to your question, but the alternate flow control style in PHP (`if/elseif/endif` and its loop cousins) are mainly intended for templating inside HTML. It's sort of unconventional to use them in straight PHP, where using the standard curly brace syntax is preferred. (`if {}`). If you're going to integrate with others' code, consider using the standard syntax instead.