# php: echo ('x' == 0) prints 1 (true). is this correct?

Tags: php

my friend and me found this while debugging an application

```php
<?php

echo "check: " . ('x' == 0);

?>
```

This code prints 1 (so, it is true, x equals to 0).
Can somebody explain why it is? I think may be I dont understand something in php rules... or may be it is a bug?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is integer 0 equal to a string in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970544/why-is-integer-0-equal-to-a-string-in-php)

Comment: try `echo intval('x');` to understand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string is converted to a number using "type juggling".  This is shown in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), too.

For this particular case, the string doesn't start with a number, so it becomes equal to 0 when cast.